# Doorknob only turns one way

Tags: lock, doorknob

This doorknob when locked spins either direction without opening. When unlocked, it used to work like a normal doorknob but now will only turn counterclockwise. Is there an easy way to fix this so it can again be turned either way to open the door?[image: doorknob on entry door]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it would previously turn either direction and now does not , this is indicative of either something physically blocking the mechanism inside or needing lubricant. Either way your solution is the same- disassemble and lubricate. Remove the knobs, then remove the latch assembly. Remove any obvious pieces of metal or debris that are present, add a lubricant, work the mechanism, and reassemble.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WX8NG0275R4

Answer (score 2):

Disassemble the door knobs from door. Leaving the latch in place determine if the latch moves in both directions (CW and CCW) and returns to center. If not, determine what is causing the interference or "drag." Lubricate as needed.

Holding the knob that interfaces with the latch in your hand, verify the knob turns in both directions and returns to center. If not, determine what is causing the interference or "drag." Lubricate as needed.

Finally holding the other knob in your hand, verify the knob turns in both directions and returns to center. If the knob only turns in one direction, then one of the rotational stops has likely slipped past the end of the torsional spring. (*The torsional spring ends limit the rotation of the knob*). Both stops need to be on the same side (*wider space*) of the spring ends. Push the spring end down and rotate knob to allow the stop to slip over the spring end. Push that spring end back up to capture the stop.

Reassemble knob and verify door knob functions properly.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Breaking your text into **digestible paragraphs** will make easier to read and understand.

Comment: Maybe it was in the original text, maybe it was in the edit, but the first two paragraphs seem to be near duplicates to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The door HANDLE spindle consists of two sections.  Make sure that your door KNOB only slides onto the section of the door handle spindle that turns both ways and not onto any portion of the spindle that turns only one way. Your door handle spindle length must be the correct length for this proper alignment to occur.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).